# Use one list as search key for another list with sublist

Tags: python

I have two lists that returns some vector values with it's own name:

```
list1 = [['orange', [1, 2, 3]]]
list2 = [['apple', [1, 2, 3]], ['banana', [1, 2, 3]], ['pear', [-1, 2, 3]], ['kiwi', [1, -2, 3]]]
```

So far I have a code that uses the list1 as a "search key" and ignoring the string on the list2 and print out the sublist that are not the same than in list1, which gives this result:

```
[['pear' [-1, 2, 3], ['kiwi', [-1, -2, 3]]]
```

This is the script:

```
S = set(tuple(x[1]) for x in list1)
result = [x for x in list2 if tuple(x[1]) not in S]
```

I would like to go futher and compare only the first value of the vector list, which the result should be:
`[['pear' [-1, 2, 3]]` only eventhough kiwi has different value but in the second item of the vector list.

Comment: What is blocking you from going further? Where are you stuck?

Comment: This is the key usage of dictionaries. Is there any reason why you are not using those?

Comment: I couldn't understand the last paragraph... you wanna break the search if the first item is found ?

Comment: Seems pretty straightforward. Go one lever deeper: `S = set(x[1][0] for x in list1)` and then `result = [x for x in list2 if x[1][0] not in S]`

Comment: Thank you, I guess the problem was having a tuple and I was forcing myself (for no reason) to keep them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the first value of `list1` into another list and use filter on `list2`

```
list1 = [['orange', [1, 2, 3]]]
list2 = [['apple', [1, 2, 3]], ['banana', [1, 2, 3]], ['pear', [-1, 2, 3]], ['kiwi', [1, -2, 3]]]

a = [l[1][0] for l in list1]
# a is [1] (first value of vector list)

list(filter(lambda x: x[1][0] not in a, list2))
# This will return expected out put i.e: [['pear', [-1, 2, 3]]]
```